# Loading partial in a popup, what is the right way to go about it?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Ok. In the users controller, on the show page, I have this `<div/>`:

```html
<div class="globalwidth" id="picshow">
</div>

<div class=fadecontent></div>
```

Also, on the users page, I have this:

```
<% @photos.each do |p| %>
<%=  link_to image_tag(p.image(:medium)), photo_path(p), remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

The above link is suppose to take the user to the photo controller's show action (_show.html.erb) which shows a larger version of the image. I would like to load this as a partial inside the `<div/>` with the id `#picshow` in the user page, using ajax, while making it look like a popup.

I created a show.js.erb inside of the photos directory...

```js
$('#picshow').html('<%=j render partial: 'photos/show' %>')
loadPopup()
```

And I am also calling this function that I have in my application.js file so that it makes it look like a popup that fades in....FYI, fadecontent is another div I have inside the user show, which should make everything behind the popup faded.

```js
var popupStatus = 0;

function loadPopup() {
    if(popupStatus==0) {
        $(".fadecontent").fadeIn("slow");
        $(".largepic").fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}

function disablePopup() {
    if(popupStatus==1) {
        $(".fadecontent").fadeOut("slow");
        $(".largepic").fadeOut("slow");
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}
```

This is the photo's show controller and action:

```
def show

@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
  format.js
    end 
 end
```

This is what I have in the _show.html.erb in the photos controller

```html
<div class="largepic">
    <div class="largeimage left">
        <%=image_tag @photo.image(:large) %>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS

```css
.largepic {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    margin: 125px auto;
    left: 15px;
    width: 930px;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.largeimage {
    padding: 18px;
}

.largeimage p {
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 19px;
    width: 450px;
}
```

Basically, I want the partial of photos/show to render as a partial in the div with the id of "picshow" while looking like a popup that can be escaped or xed out of. It has no display by default. The fadeIn in the loadPopup function makes it show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've mentioned that AJAX is your main concern, here is a working example.  This example initially loads the smaller image.  Upon clicking the smaller image, uses AJAX to load the larger image and on escape key resets the photo back to smaller image.  You should be able to modify it to achieve your goal.

app/views/photos/index.html.erb

```
<div id="photo-image">
    <%= render partial: 'photos/photo_image', locals: { width: 50, height: 64 } 5>
</div>
```

app/views/photos/_photo_image.html.erb

```
<%= link_to image_tag('rails.png', width: "#{width}", height: "#{height}", photo_path(1), remote: true %>
```

app/views/photos/show.js.erb

```
$('#photo-image').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'photos/photo_image', locals: { width: '110', height: '128' }) %>")

$(document).keyup(function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
        $('#photo-image').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'photos/photo_image', locals: { width: '50', height: '64' }) %>")
    }
});
```

app/controllers/photos_controller.rb

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
    def show 
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
    end
end
```

I hope this solves your problem.  Please comment if you need any explanation.

Update: Your question has "Loading partial in a popup" but no where in your description you say "popup".  If you'd like to display the partial on popup, you would need to update the app/views/photos/show.js.erb.  I hope you will figure that one out.

Comment: Hi Vinodad...do you have skype? I cannot upvote your post for some reason. I'm trying to do a fadein with the popup and stuff, and I suppose I should've showed more code. Can I edit my post and show you exactly what I'm doing?

Comment: Sure @SaraAlnuaimi, please update your original post with your updated code.  I would suggest you append to your post so that others could benefit from it, in that everyone could see your original post and your updated code.  That helps everyone.  Hey don't worry about voting, we all are here to work together; getting voted up and voted down is not the ambition.

Comment: Basically, my code doesn't load the partial inside the div. It just goes to a redirects to the photo show page.

Comment: You shouldn't get redirected as long as you have the `remote: true` option in your `link_to`, which I see you do.  Plus you do not need `app/views/photos/show.html.erb` for this case because you want to load photos via ajax.  You only need `app/views/photos/show.js.erb`.  The problem is somewhere else if you are still getting redirected.

Comment: I have html content in my show.html.erb that I am showing outside of the photo. Is there more elegant way of displaying /photos/show.html.erb in a popup outside of what I am trying to do because it is just not working.